# is Global Concurrent Queue was shared with all the currenlty running process in iOS or Each Process has it's own set of Global Concurrent Queue?

Tags: ios, concurrency

is Global Concurrent Queue was shared with all the currenlty running process in iOS or Each Process has it's own set of Global Concurrent Queue ?

Answer (score 2):

from Apple Docs:

> ***The system provides each application with four concurrent dispatch
>   queues.*** These queues are global to the application and are
>   differentiated only by their priority level. ***Because they are global,
>   you do not create them explicitly. Instead, you ask for one of the
>   queues using the dispatch_get_global_queue function***, as shown in the
>   following example:

```
dispatch_queue_t aQueue =
*emphasized text*dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
```

see more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW5)

Comment: "These queues are global" , what this means, Main Queue is also available to entire application. is it not Global ?

Comment: Main Queue is for foreground (UI tasks). In case you will use main queue for task which not related to UI then some of your long calculated (performed ) task can freeze UI ( make worse the responsibility of your app). global queue is for background tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Every iPhone or iPad app is run in a sandbox. What this means is that it is completely separate from every other app as well as the system. Both it's memory and storage space are sandboxed as well as the queues that it is running off of. Each global/main queue is created for the application that is using it through grand central dispatch.

Furthermore, when an Application is open and in use, it will be using the main queue, its main queue. Any other applications open in the background will not be using this same queue and will also be operation on its own background queue.

Comment: "These queues are global" , what this means, Main Queue is also available to entire application. is it not Global ?

Comment: Global means it is available across the entire application. Yes, the main queue is global A global queue is not a specific queue, just a statement referring to a generic queue across the application.